# Matlab scatterhist add percentage in histogram side

Tags: matlab, histogram, scatter-plot

I would like to get and/or add in scatterhist plot, info about the histogram percentage above bars, or just to get this info.

For example in:
[image: Text] I need to know how much is the percentage in each bar for vv1 and vv2

something like that:
[image: Text]

IS it possible to do that in Matlab? I care more about the information, not so much about the plot.

any help would be more than welcome!
Gas

Answer (score -1):

As for getting Values on the Bars you can find an example [here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/40629-bar-plot-value-on-top).

scatterhist creates 3 "plots" in 1 figure, so you need to create a handle like [here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/521848-adding-axes-to-histogram-on-scatterhist-and-changing-graph-area) (also useful if you just want axis) using `h = scatterhist(...);`
and then seleting your bargraph inside the Figure by its index eg.: `h(3)`.

Comment: I have found the posts you wrote, but are not helpful to me! I need to know how in the next simply example:
scatterhist(log(rand(1,100)),log(rand(1,100)),'Marker','o','Direction','out');
I could add or get the info of what is the percentage in each bar.

Comment: If you created a Handle for the whole figure using 

"handle = scatterhist(log(rand(1,100)),log(rand(1,100)),'Marker','o','Direction','out');"

you can get the data that rand produced with 

"handle(1,3).Children.Data"

and the Values of the Histogram with 

"handle(1,3).Children.Values"

Is that what you meant?